# linux software regarding filename

Tags: bash

IN Raj's GNU/LINUX system there are a set of files and folders in his home dirctory (located in /home/raj). He wants to locate all pdf files which begin with the character sequence "lib" and contain the number "23" somewhere in the filename. What command should he type on command line to locate those files.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Is this *homework*?

Comment: yes , it is for me ,if u know than answer it...........

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find /home/raj -name "lib*23*.pdf"
```